# TypeScript yet another `prop` function with non-existence key

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

How do I type a `prop` function that returns a default type when the key doesn't exist on the object `o`?

```
type Prop = <K, O extends {}>(k: K, o: O) =>
  K extends keyof O
    ? O[K]
    : 'Nah';

/*
Argument of type 'K' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | 
  number | symbol'.
  Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
*/
const p: Prop = (k, o) => o.hasOwnProperty(k) ? o[k] : 'Nah';

p('non-existence-property', { n: 1 });

/*
Type '"Nah" | O[K]' is not assignable to type 'K extends keyof O ? O[K] : "Nah"'.
  Type '"Nah"' is not assignable to type 'K extends keyof O ? O[K] : "Nah"'.
*/
const p1 = <K, O extends {}>(k: K, o: O): K extends keyof O ? O[K] : 'Nah' =>
    o.hasOwnProperty(k) ? o[k] : 'Nah';
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but `extends {}` is probably better written as `extends object` if you want to constrain `O` to be an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to aid in type inference when calling `p()`, let's alter the definition of `Prop` slightly:

```
type Prop = <K extends keyof any, O extends {}>(k: K, o: O) =>
  K extends keyof O
  ? O[K]
  : 'Nah';
```

I've just restricted `K` to be `string | number | symbol`, which is probably what you meant anyway, and has the benefit that functions of type `Prop` will tend to infer `K` to be string literals instead of `string`.

---

The main problem you're having is that it's not really possible for the compiler to verify if a type is assignable to an unresolved conditional type (`T extends U ? X : Y` when `T` or `U` depend on unspecified/uninferred generic type parameters).  Generic functions returning conditional types are meant to make *caller's* lives easier; the *implementer* is more or less stuck using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to appease the compiler:

```
const p: Prop = (k: any, o: any) => o.hasOwnProperty(k) ? o[k] : 'Nah'; // no error
```

The annotation of `k` and `o` as `any` allows us to write our own implementation without the compiler complaining.  Of course, this is not type-safe, and we must be very careful not to lie to the compiler.  Which, technically, we have:

```
// missing optional keys  
const val: { a?: number } = (1 > 2) ? { a: 1 } : {};
const oops1 = p("a", val); // definitely "Nah" at runtime, 
// but number | undefined at compile time, oops!

// subtypes with unknown extra keys
interface Animal { limbs: number; }
interface Cat extends Animal { lives: number; }
const cat: Cat = { limbs: 4, lives: 9 };
const animal: Animal = cat;
const oops2 = p("lives", animal); // definitely number at runtime, 
// but "Nah" at compile time, oops!

// prototype properties 
const regex = /hey/;
const oops3 = p("exec", regex); // definitely "Nah" at runtime, 
// but function at compile time, oops!
```

These are all situations where your assumption that `p` implements `Prop` is shown to be incorrect.  There are probably others, too.  Only you know if your use cases are such where these situations don't matter.  Maybe they don't matter, but you should be aware of it.

Anyway, I hope that helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Still hate type systems :)

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing your version

The simplest fix to your version is to constrain `K` with `extends string`:

```
type Prop = <K extends string, O extends {}>(k: K, o: O) => /*...*/
```

The issue is that when you call your function like `prop("foo", {foo: 'value'})` the type params are being filled in as `prop<string, {foo: string}>` - since `K` is generic 'string', it fails the `keyof O` check and you get `"Nah"`.

Adding the `extends string` constraint will cause the params to instead be filled as `prop<"foo", {foo: string}>`, which functions as you'd expect.

---

However, I don't think this version is probably what you want.  The issue is that if TS can't prove at compile-time, that your key is part of the object, the type is going to be `"Nah"`:

```
// According to TS, always returns "Nah", but in reality, it might not be.
function test(obj: object, someKey: string) {
    return prop(someKey, obj);
}
```

#### Alternative:

As an alternative, I'd suggest this:

```
function prop1<O>(k: string, o: O): O[keyof O] | "Nah" {
    return o.hasOwnProperty(k) ?
        o[k as keyof O] : 'Nah'; 
}
```

The main difference from your version is that we're not doing anything conditional here: the whole idea is that we don't know if `k` is a key of `O` or not, so it doesn't help us much to do conditionals: either it'll return a value in `O` (`O[keyof O]`) or else it'll return "Nah".

If you do know, at compile time, that `k` is a keyof `O`?  You could add overloads to this function to handle that case, but it gets complicated, and you're probably better off just doing `o[k]` and not using this function at all.